# ICalendar event cancelation not working in Outlook

Tags: outlook-2007, icalendar

I am using Outlook 2007 and cannot get the way to cancel event via importing *.ics file.
Using the `METHOD:CANCEL` and `STATUS:CANCELLED` properties I can cancel events in Google Calendar but not in Outlook 2007. It creates duplicate events. I tried to set `X-WR-RELCALID` tag in header, however it's still creating duplicate records.

If anyone can provide working example I'll appreciate it.

Examples:

Insert:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR`
`VERSION:2.0`
 
`PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN`
`BEGIN:VEVENT`
`DTSTART:20130906T094830Z`
`DTEND:20130906T101830Z`
`DTSTAMP:20130906T163053Z`
`UID:MyUID402`
`DESCRIPTION:Test Description`
`LOCATION:Test Location`
`ORGANIZER:MAILTO:test@gmail.com`
`SEQUENCE:0`
`SUMMARY:Test Summary`
`TRANSP:OPAQUE`
`END:VEVENT`
`END:VCALENDAR`

And Cancel:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR`
`VERSION:2.0`
`PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN`
`METHOD:CANCEL`
`BEGIN:VEVENT`
`DTSTART:20130906T094830Z`
`DTEND:20130906T101830Z`
`DTSTAMP:20130906T163053Z`
`UID:MyUID402`
`DESCRIPTION:Test Description`
`LOCATION:Test Location`
`ORGANIZER:MAILTO:test@gmail.com`
`SEQUENCE:1`
`STATUS:CANCELLED`
`SUMMARY:Test Summary`
`TRANSP:OPAQUE`
`END:VEVENT`
`END:VCALENDAR`

So it works perfectly in Google Calendar but for some reason it doesn't work for Outlook.
The same result is with `X-WR-RELCALID` tag.

Comment: You might want to give us the full VCALENDAR stream. Did you make sure that the UID corresponds to the event you are trying to cancel. But then, it is well possible that Outlok will consider cancel only if they are coming through your Inbox (as opposed to through import).

Comment: Thanx for your reply, I posted examples above.